# SSRS Report Development for D365 - Dynamics 365 Report Authoring Extension is not Getting Installed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, dynamics-365

I want to create a SSRS report for Dynamcis 365 online.
While preparing the development environment the Dynamics 365
Report Authoring Extension is not getting installed with message "some of the required components are missing". Which component am I missing here? Any idea?

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDQj2.png)

I did install visual studio 2015 enterprise with SSDT

[VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w4ej.png)

I can see in visual studio - SQL Server Data Tool 14.0.60519.0 is installed
.Net Framework version 4.7.03190
and SQL Server 2016 Enterprise With SSRS Installed and configured.

Here is the installation log file content of the latest attempt -

```
03:53:27|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 9/1/2019 3:53:27 AM ===
03:53:27|   Info| Bootstrap version: 8.2.2.248.
03:53:28|   Info| User: Administrator.
03:53:31|   Info| No pending reboot detected
03:53:32|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

03:54:34|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 9/1/2019 3:54:34 AM ===
03:54:34|   Info| Bootstrap version: 8.2.2.248.
03:54:34|   Info| User: Administrator.
03:54:34|   Info| No pending reboot detected
03:54:34|   Info| Current OS Version: 6.2.9200
03:54:34|   Info|   ServicePack: 
03:54:34|   Info|   System Type: Workstation
03:54:34|   Info|   Suite Mask: 0x0190
03:54:34|   Info| Initializing COM.
03:54:35|   Info| Initialized COM.
03:54:35|   Info| CIsVcRedist12Installed=1
03:54:35|   Info| VCRedist 12 with version 12.0.21005  is already installed
03:54:35|   Info| Initializing COM.
03:54:35|   Info| Initialized COM.
03:54:35|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
03:54:35|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
03:54:35|   Info| Running prereq checks
03:54:35|   Info| DotNet v4 Release value: 460805
03:54:36|   Info| IsDotNetInstalled=1
03:54:36|   Info| IsDrWatsonInstalled=1
03:54:36|   Info| CIsMSOIDCRL64Installed=1
03:54:36|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
03:54:36|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
03:54:39|   Info| Waiting for PrereqCheck to be signaled
03:54:39|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 9/1/2019 3:54:39 AM ===
03:54:40|   Info| === Managed setup logging started: 9/1/2019 3:54:40 AM ===
03:54:40|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.BidsExtensions.BidsExtensionsSetup.Initialize
03:54:40|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.SetupBase.Initialize
03:54:40|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.SetupBase.Initialize
03:54:40|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.BidsExtensions.BidsExtensionsSetup.Initialize
03:54:40|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.BidsExtensions.BidsExtensionsSetup.Run
03:54:41|   Info| CrmAction execution time; CollectAction; 00:00:00
03:54:41|   Info| CrmAction execution time; CollectAction; 00:00:00.0313378
03:54:41|Verbose| Installing version component: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\MSCRM_{1AAFE585-0B2E-4BF0-8E69-103478FEE4C9}\Setup\crmverbidsextensions.dll
03:54:41|Verbose| Installing version: 8.2.2.248
03:54:41|Verbose| Installing lcid: 1033
03:54:41|   Info| CrmAction execution time; CollectAction; 00:00:00.3593764
03:54:41|   Info| CrmAction execution time; CollectAction; 00:00:00.3593753
03:54:41|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.SetupBase.Run
03:54:41|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.SetupBase.Run
03:54:41|   Info| ConfigurationValidator linking to help topic: html/54e163ea-ca95-43ee-a300-30f4d696df99.htm 
03:54:41|   Info| CrmAction execution time; CollectAction; 00:00:00.0155010
03:54:41|   Info| CrmAction execution time; ValidateAction; 00:00:00
03:54:41|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.BidsExtensions.BidsExtensionsSetup.RunInternal
03:54:43|   Info| TargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/59e4e570-a944-4dcc-ab79-829605e26bf9.htm 
03:54:43|   Info| Setup thread-routine provided to progress wizard
03:54:43|   Info| ActivatePage(MUOptInPage)
03:54:43|   Info| Window Left: 663
03:54:43|   Info| Window Top: 316
03:54:47|   Info| ActivatePage(BidsExtensionsInstallLocationPage)
03:54:47|   Info| TargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/59e4e570-a944-4dcc-ab79-829605e26bf9.htm 
03:54:47|   Info| TargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/59e4e570-a944-4dcc-ab79-829605e26bf9.htm 
03:54:47|   Info| TargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/59e4e570-a944-4dcc-ab79-829605e26bf9.htm 
03:54:55|   Info| TargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/59e4e570-a944-4dcc-ab79-829605e26bf9.htm 
03:54:55|   Info| PeerTargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/4d26c434-d40d-434c-8ad1-c7ca3e2f6063.htm 
03:54:55|   Info| CrmAction execution time; ValidateAction; 00:00:00
03:54:55|   Info| CrmAction execution time; ValidateAction; 00:00:00
03:54:55|   Info| TargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/59e4e570-a944-4dcc-ab79-829605e26bf9.htm 
03:54:55|   Info| ActivatePage(DiagnosticsPage)
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.AdminTargetFolder: 
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.AllowRun: True
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.CleanupRequired: False
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.CreateDatabase: True
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.CurrentFolder: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\MSCRM_{1AAFE585-0B2E-4BF0-8E69-103478FEE4C9}
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.InstallAlways: False
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.InstallingPackage: C:\Users\Administrator\BIDSExtensions.msi
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.InstallType: Install
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.LocalPackage: 
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.LogFile: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MSCRM\Logs\BIDSExtensionsSetup.log
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.MUOptIn: True
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.PackageName: BIDSExtensions.msi
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.RebootRequired: False
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.RemoteInstall: False
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.RunEdwChecks: True
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.Setup: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.BidsExtensions.BidsExtensionsSetup
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.SharedInstall: False
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.SourceFolder: C:\Users\Administrator
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.SuppressReboot: False
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.TargetFolder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.UIMode: Full
03:54:55|   Info| InstallInfo.UserCancel: False
03:54:55|   Info| IpcInfo.NoLock: False
03:54:55|   Info| ProductInfo.Features: System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary
03:54:55|   Info| ProductInfo.InstallingLanguage: 1033
03:54:55|   Info| ProductInfo.InstallingProductCode: 0c524df0-0409-0080-bf3e-80d80b490d53
03:54:55|   Info| ProductInfo.InstallingVersion: 8.2.2.248
03:54:55|   Info| ProductInfo.InstallState: Unknown
03:54:55|   Info| SystemInfo.MachineName: MININT-F36S5EH
03:54:55|   Info| SystemInfo.OSVersion: 6.2.9200.0
03:54:55|   Info| SystemInfo.ServicePackVersion: 0.0
03:54:55|   Info| UserInfo.AccountName: Administrator
03:54:55|   Info| UserInfo.DomainName: MININT-F36S5EH
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.SNG.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GathererCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GathererCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.SNG.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolCallbacks.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolCallbacks.Clear
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolCallbacks.Clear
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolCallbacks.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.Constructor
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.PropagateContext
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.PropagateContext
03:54:55|   Info| BidsInstalledValidator linking to help topic: html/8674e45c-707c-435b-8359-0cb9b9c16983.htm 
03:54:55|   Info| TargetFolderValidator linking to help topic: html/59e4e570-a944-4dcc-ab79-829605e26bf9.htm 
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.PropagateContext
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.PropagateContext
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Clear
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Clear
03:54:55|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Clear
03:54:55|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Clear
03:54:56|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.RunAll(False)
03:54:56|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Clear
03:54:56|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolResults.Clear
03:54:56|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.Run(False, (null))
03:54:56|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.PropagateContext
03:54:56|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.PropagateContext
03:54:56|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:56|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GroupCollection.Constructor()
03:54:56|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GathererCollection.Constructor()
03:54:56|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.GathererCollection.Constructor()
03:54:56|Verbose| Built gatherer and sniffer collections.
03:54:56|Verbose| Cleanup completed.
03:54:56|Verbose| Calling sniffer collect.
03:54:56|Verbose| Calling sniffer collect.
03:54:56|Verbose| Collection ran.
03:54:56|Verbose| Collection completed.
03:54:56|Verbose| Gatherers ran.
03:54:56|Verbose| Gathering completed.
03:54:56|Verbose| Calling sniffer process.
03:54:56|Verbose| Calling sniffer process.
03:54:56|Verbose| Processing ran.
03:54:56|Verbose| Processing completed.
03:54:56|   Info| Group Environment Checks
03:54:56|  Error| Check BidsInstalledValidator : Failure: Some of the required components are missing. For more information, click Details.
03:54:56|   Info| Group User Input Checks
03:54:56|   Info| Check TargetFolderValidator: Success
03:54:56|Verbose| Validation ran.
03:54:56|Verbose| Validation completed.
03:54:56|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.Run
03:54:56|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWTool.RunAll
03:54:56|Verbose| Method entry: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolCallbacks.Clear
03:54:56|Verbose| Method exit: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.EDWToolCallbacks.Clear
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is resolved when I run the SSDT installer separately from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017

SSDT installed with Visual Studio itself is not enough. I downloaded version 17.4 for visual studio 2015 and installed separately.

After this separate installation of SSDT Dynamics 365 Report Authoring Extension got installed without any complain. Thanks everyone for your helping attitude!!

Comment: In top of that, I also needed to restart my computer after installing the SSDT.

Comment: @colinD that's interesting to know :)

Answer (score 1):

The system requirements for the Microsoft Dynamics 365 Report Authoring Extension are listed in the first link I posted.

To save you some time, I will post them here as well.

Supported Operating System
Windows 10 , Windows Vista, Windows XP

The following operating systems are supported:

- Windows 10
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows 8

  - Windows 7

One of the following Microsoft Visual Studio and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools combinations are required:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015
  Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012
- Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Data Tools
- To install SQL Server Data Tools, on the PC running Visual Studio 2010 go to the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express download page, download the following files appropriate to your CPU architecture and language:
  ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
  ENU\x86\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe

Select the "SSDT" or "SQL Server Data Tools" installation.

Note:
Microsoft Dynamics 365 Report Authoring Extension is available only in a 32-bit version.

[image]

Link for Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/on-premises/microsoft-dynamics-365-reporting-requirements

Comment: thanks @AnkUser for the information. I've checked this before and I still can't understand what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload the installation log for us to make further investigation?

Comment: This is not an answer, you should comment in question.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jeff. I've added the installation log content in the original questions.